Subscribe to Partner Topic in Event Grid Using Logic Apps
I can't subscribe to a partner topic using logic apps. If I try using the event grid connector in logic app, I'm not able to find the partner topic. If I use a when http request arrives endpoint and then try to create an event subscription in the topic using the logic app endpoint, it fails. Ideally, I would like to use the event grid connector directly in logic apps but the documentation isn't great.

Can you share the workflow which you have tried


In Event Grid Connector, you can see the system topics and custom topics only.
For partner topic, you can use the webhook endpoints of logic app while creating event subscription and it does work.
I have created the below given logic app workflow which will subscribe to the partner topic.



Then, created an event subscription in Event Grid Partner topic as given below.



Upon user creation, deletion or updation, my logic app is getting trigger automatically.



Did this answer help you? @JJames
